# Synchonizing time settings in dual-boot (Ubuntu & Windows XP)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, multi-boot

I have installed dual-boot os Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows XP, but I have a problem with the time settings.

When I set the time in Windows XP then it automatically changes the time settings in Ubuntu. How can I sort out the time settings problem with dual-boot Operating Systems?

Regards
Abdul

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both Ubuntu and Windows are both in the proper timezones and are both obeying DST or any other settings the same way. Depending on the way your OS is interpreting the system clock, you may run into situations where the two fight each other in the way you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Ubuntu uses UTC whereas Windows uses localtime and both set the hardware clock according to their philosophy and expect it to be that way the next time they get booted. 
Change `UTC=yes` to `UTC=no` `/etc/default/rcS` then both systems use localtime.